# Fail testNG @Test before assertion is evaluated

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, testng

I want to fail a testNG test (@Test) if during a run of test any of the test steps throw an exception such as NoSuchElementException. (Just for example)

In current scenario I am checking if I click on a particular task then some text appears in an element on UI. But recently AUT threw a network error on clicking of task and hence the element which contains text that I am verifying did not appear on UI. So webdriver threw NoSuchElementException. But as all my assertions are somewhere in the later part of the test steps TestNG marked this test as pass and hence went ahead with executing dependent test cases as well.

So is there a way to fail a test if all the steps in the test were not executed or if any exception is thrown?

Here is the sample code:

```
public class DummyTest {

@Test
public void testThis(){
    try{
        testThisSteps();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void testThisSteps() throws Exception{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://toolsqa.com/automation-practice-form/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h1[text()='Practice Automation']"));
    int i = driver.findElements(By.name("firstname")).size();
    Assert.assertTrue(i!=0,"Element does not exist even though page is loaded");
  }
}
```

Now the question is if webdriver is not able to find element in this case I have purposely left out some text after the maximize code it will throw NoSuchElementExeception and further code will not be executed which results in assertion not getting evaluated and test case execution is stopped with further test cases dependent on this getting executed. Here is the execution result:-

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//h1[text()='Practice Automation']"}

*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//h1[text()='Practice Automation']

Default Suite

Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Spontaneously it sounds if the test does not make sense if some error appear. Would @beforetest be a solution? This will skip the test if the beforetest method fails.

Comment: you can throw an exception at any point in your `testng` tests.

Comment: 1. Don't put your test code under `try-except`block, so the exception will be raised and given to TestNG. then TestNG can mark it as an error in the test. 2. Revisit your Assertions, which are getting successful despite the network errors (Assertion get passed, look suspicious to me).

Comment: @Naveen actually the issue is assertions are not getting evaluated altogether as I mentioned that my assertions are in the later part of the test steps and those steps are skipped as I am expecting a webelement with particular text which throws NoSuchElementException and testNG proceeds to execute next test case in the test suite.

Comment: so, what happened with that test method? marked as passed/failed/error? please share the test method code.

Comment: @Naveen We cannot share the code due to policy restrictions but I will come up with something generic in a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the code inside the test, is surrounded with `try-catch` block. If you add `throws Exception` to the method definition and no `try-except`, you can get the behaviour as the test method marked as `Fail`, instead of `Pass` when any exception is thrown apart from `Assertions`.

I tried the following code which throws `NoSuchElementException` (to simulate your question):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.asserts.Assertion;

public class SeleniumTests {


    @Test()
    public void testmethod() throws  Exception{
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        driver.findElement(By.className("something")); // throws NoSuchElementException
        Assert.assertEquals(true, false);
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

Here, as the element with class name `"something"` is not present, throws `NoSuchElementException`.

`Assert.assertEquals` is not executed.

TestNG marked it as `Failed`. Is this the behaviour you are expecting?

Following is the complete log:

```
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\USER_HP_2013_03\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse--1064112655\testng-customsuite.xml

Starting ChromeDriver 2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed) on port 10078
Only local connections are allowed.
Jan 04, 2017 5:10:03 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Jan 04, 2017 5:10:06 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
FAILED: testmethod
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"something"}
  (Session info: chrome=55.0.2883.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 42 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700'
System info: host: 'HP201303', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_73'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed), userDataDir=C:\Users\USER_H~1\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir5260_26036}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=55.0.2883.87, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 92cbb27a874d7d2215eee51fc6a77819
*** Element info: {Using=class name, value=something}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:635)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:368)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByClassName(RemoteWebDriver.java:457)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByClassName.findElement(By.java:391)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:360)
    at SeleniumTests.testmethod(SeleniumTests.java:14)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@35bbe5e8: 9 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@2a18f23c: 12 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@4ec6a292: 27 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@3f0ee7cb: 9 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 4 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@66d33a: 8 ms
```

Comment: Let me try this. I have edited the question anyways I think you have rectified the issue that I am facing correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This question really depends on the required behaviour that the OP is after.

Your options are:
a) Put another assertion on the element that failed to appear on the UI
(probably not ideal as you want to verify your tests on a given cause rather than individual elements, i.e. successfully logged in instead of 'clicked login button'

b) Use testng annotation to control flow and required behaviour `dependsOnMethods="yourMethodContainingTheElementThatOccassionallyAppears"`

c) Avoid catching the exception so testng will fail that step (and if you also use solution (b) rest of the tests will be skipped (denoted in yellow)

d) Capture the SeleniumNoEmentException and then make an assertion regarding elementPresent within the try/catch block. By adjusting dependencies accordingly, you can decide if you want your script to persist or skip the rest of the steps.

e) Use a softAssertion (meaning that if the element does not appear again in the future your test won't fail but continue running the rest of the steps

Hope this helps!

Comment: Actually what I am looking for is the mechanism to fail a test case if any of the test steps throw an exception. I have already used dependsOnMethods, dependsOnGroups, softAssertions etc.And for the option a) that you have suggested this will apply in particular for that statement only but I am looking for a solution to mark test as fail if any of the test step fails (throws exception) irrespective of if that particular step is an assertion or not.

Comment: But this is standard testNG behaviour (i.e. if a step fails the whole test case is marked as a fail). Perhaps sharing some code can help! :) I'm guessing that you already using some form of try/catch in your code and you are capturing the exception thown that's why your test is marked as passed..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
try {
    driver.findElement(by.xpath("//h1[text()='Practice Automation']");
}catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e){
     assert.fail("the element I was attempting to location was not found.");
}
```

It is a cheap hacky way to do what you are trying but it will work and an assertion will be triggered.

Also your try catch block is the reason the test is not failing. You are handling the failure in the test by catching it

```
try{
    testThisSteps();
}catch(Exception e){
    // you caught the failure. No error will pop up because it was caught
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

by catching you are literally forcing the test to pass.